# Cannot connect to chocolatey.org or any other internet site from within container

Tags: docker, windows

xpost from https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-chocolatey-org/38745

#### Expected behavior

I'm running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (MSDN download) 64 bit - Version 1607 - Build 14393.1715

I'm using Docker For Windows and running Windows Containers.

I figure this is the easiest thing in the world, to do this:

```
reboot my host machine
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore
powershell
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
```

The expectation is for this to install chocolatey in the container.

*I'm actually going to be doing this in a dockerfile, but I'm going for minimum working example to get help right now.*

Here's an actual docker file that fails (it's not so creative, sadly)

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["Powershell"]

ENV ChocolateyUseWindowsCompression false;
RUN iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
```

#### Actual behavior

First things first: I'm running this in a Virtualbox VM. Everything else that I want to work works, including but not limited to: internal network connectivity and tests, sql server running, WCF services running against my docker-compose environment, data coming back correctly. All of the things I expect the system to do are working. This is the last-step, fingers crossed :D. The fact that I'm running this in VirtualBox shouldn't matter, since the Hyper-V is working and all my machines are working as expected. I just figure it's worth mentioning.

```
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore
powershell
PS C:\> iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote name could not be resolved: 'chocolatey.org'"
At line:1 char:1
+ iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.or ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

PS C:\> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 339189e8dd56
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : attlocal.net

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Container NIC 6412b757):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : attlocal.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-80-E9-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a51b:820e:e45d:fab6%29(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.202.147(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.192.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.192.1
                                       10.0.2.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

From my host OS (Server 2016) I have this information:

```
PS C:\docker> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-CDPNLUMSTOE
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : attlocal.net

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC) 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-80-E5-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5939:52e7:aaf3:5b70%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.192.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301995357
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-4E-0C-48-08-00-27-51-5F-6A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC) 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-B6-45-8D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1de4:bff7:36fb:ee92%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.128.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 570430813
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-4E-0C-48-08-00-27-51-5F-6A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : attlocal.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-51-5F-6A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10de:923b:b866:221d%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 19, 1881 6:47:42 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 26, 2017 11:15:59 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50855975
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-4E-0C-48-08-00-27-51-5F-6A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C420BD56-5715-49BF-9382-5EA99AA48563}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{70EA4F39-FE0F-4040-B718-ACAC00765808}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.attlocal.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : attlocal.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
PS C:\docker>
```

#### Information

DockerDebugInfo.ps1 output: https://gist.github.com/jcolebrand/170673e45bf8a659552f22f2071c30d6

#### System information

Running Windows Server Datacenter (MSDN download) 64 bit - Version 1607 - Build 14393.1715

```
PS C:\docker> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:57:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:59:47 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

*If, for any forsaken reason this is important, the host OS does need to be activated. I'm doing this in a one-shot dev environment so wasn't particularly worried about activating the VM just yet. I can't fathom how this is important. Especially since everything else "just works".*

Comment: It seems like there is a similar issue posted here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/427 Try stopping and starting the docker service.

Comment: Thanks @PrestonM I did that many times. And rebooted the computer. And get-netnat|remove-netnat

Comment: running `Stop-Service docker; Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork -Force; Start-Service docker` presents a couple issues. no service found with name docker. no container networks found with Get-ContainerNetwork

Comment: where are you running the command from? Virtualbox, or Windows Server?

Comment: @PrestonM A little confused. Let me recap my setup: OSX Host -> VirtualBox -> Windows Server 2016 -> Docker for Windows -> container. The stack is all running on Hyper-V layers, and I can do everything else I ask on my containers, including internal network communication between apps and a local database instance (microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer) so everything that I want to do is fine. The commands are being issued in a powershell term on the container. The Server2016 can reach the internet fine.

Comment: It seems this is similar to [No external network connectivity from inside Docker container](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-external-network-connectivity-from-inside-docker-container/8045). Many suggestions, including changing DNS server, are mentioned.

Comment: Gotcha. I skipped over the OSX part and thought you were running virtual box on server 2016

Comment: @AndrewT. that issue is different in my expectation because that's the HOST not being able to talk to the internet, no? I can pull images just fine.

Comment: So here's the best part today: I goto demonstrate for IT. So that we can troubleshoot what it MIGHT be. NAT on NAT (vmhost -> docker container), so direct network cable, etc. AND IT WORKS. It just works. We changed nothing. So I'm gonna try and get back to failure reproducible.

Comment: @jcole so could it be your usual network connectivity from osx causing problem? How is the windows guest networking configured? Nat or bridge? (reading on phone I may have missed the information)

Comment: @Tensibai on the OSX -> VirtualBox it's NAT, I was getting ready to switch to bridge but then there were other issues so ... I was testing with them on NAT to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I suspect a glitch on the hyper-v side for DNS forwarding, or maybe just a negative cache from a request done at a time there was no outside connectivity, windows has this bad habit of caching NXDOMAIN answers.

Comment: That starts to make sense that it would have been from a layer mismatch, but I was also on my home WiFi with the same laptop and the same issue. I hoped it would resolve itself. Looks like toggling the host VMs nic ended up resolving the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the Windows images configure DNS to first be the default gateway of the NAT interface, and then the DNS of the host machine.  DNS lookups fail against that first resolver and external access.

Adding `--dns 8.8.8.8` (or your local resolver) to the CLI seems to work around the problem.

Comment: That's awesome. Who can get this on a backlog for resolution? :D

Comment: @jcolebrand Hi, I am also facing the same issue. I have corporate proxy configuration. Where do we need to add that dns configuration? In daemon.json ?

Comment: Did you try on the command as indicated in this answer?

Comment: @jcolebrand  Tried with `docker build --dns 8.8.8.8 -t choco .` did not work. Then I added `"dns": ["8.8.8.8"]` in daemon.json did not work.

Comment: I thought the dns flag was at run not at build?

Answer (score 4):

At a command prompt run `ipconfig /all` and look for a `DNS Servers` line in the output with something that looks like an IP address. That's your host machine's DNS server(s).

Edit `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` and add a `dns` entry with that IP address. For example, if your DNS Server is 192.10.0.2 and 8.8.8.8 is Google's DNS as a backup:

```
{
    "dns": ["192.10.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Now restart Docker Desktop and the remote URLs can be resolved by Docker, either at build or runtime.

This solution came from Faithful Anere at https://medium.com/@faithfulanere/solved-docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-anything-9ea4dfdcdcf2

Answer (score 2):

As comments are transient, here's some info for the next person trying to solve this problem. Please feel free to edit this answer to provide more details, unless you're a Docker for Windows pro, in which case please give a better answer :D

I went to demo the problem for my IT group after having changed my NIC on my VM to bridged and adding my thunderbolt adapter. As there are security systems in place, I realized I needed to add the security software to my VM, but as it isn't joined to the domain, that was a problem. Switching it back to NAT on the wifi adapter, and then going to demo the problem in my Windows 2016 VM somehow magically made it start working.

Same network. Same VM configuration. Same software and host, no changes to anything I can track.

Having checked Get-ContainerNetwork or Get-WinNat showing nothing, I really had been at my end of diagnostics. Changing that NIC adapter and then changing it back apparently caused something to reset. Good times.

So, I don't have a solid answer, but I have a good workaround for the next person stuck in my shoes, which, given my track record of StackExchange questions and answers, will be me. But I hope it helps you out too, random internet asker.

---

And an XKCD tax, for those impossible to solve problems.

[image: XKCD Comic Link to "Wisdom of the ancients"]

Comment: According to this description, I'm tempted to put a bill on a DNS cache cleared by the shut/no shut of the network stack as Windows have this kind idea to cache negative request also. If it comes to happen again,  may worth trying a `ipconfig /flushdns` on the windows host

Comment: Meant to add, the host in this case is OSX, if you mean the base OS hosting everything. If you mean where I'm running the docker container, that's windows.

Comment: I mean the windows host, I don't remember *nix based   network stacks caching negative queries

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this frustrating problem but I managed to fix it today.

What I did, is in the desktop app on Windows / Mac you can edit the Daemon file. Under Settings in the Docker App under Docker Engine, I added the line at the bottom of the file just above the last curly brace. `"dns": [ "192.168.4.100", "8.8.8.8" ]`

This then allows the Docker Containers all that you now build to use your host's DNS server. Technically if you can access: https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 then you should be able to access the choco repository.

I have also built the image in https://github.com/jasric89/vsts-agent-docker/tree/master/windows/servercore/10.0.14393 and labeled it in the repo:

microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1358

I then set: `RUN choco feature enable --name allowGlobalConfirmation` before my first Choco Install command, this enables choco to install all the files and not error.

With all that set my Docker File Ran and built the image. Well in my Test Env now testing in my prod env. :)

Links that helped me:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24928
https://github.com/jasric89/vsts-agent-docker/blob/master/windows/servercore/10.0.14393/standard/VS2017/Dockerfile
https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25537

Answer (score -1):

Try installation instructions from https://chocolatey.org/install#completely-offline-install (section "Installing behind a proxy"):

```
    @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

Comment: You're answering a different question here, the question is why the container can't resolve internet addresses