# Weird behavior of the Docker Client on Windows 10

Tags: docker, networking

There is an - as perceived - unsystematic behaviour of Docker client to setup an IPv6 connection to registry, even if this is disabled in `daemon.json`.

Client error:

```
dial tcp: lookup ******** on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:PORT->
[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Registry-side error (actually same - will recheck for port numbers however):
or response from daemon:

```
    Get https://******.**:8080/v2/: dial tcp: lookup ******.** 
on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:PORT->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Possible known workarounds:

1. Restart your computer (nice that this seems an ever-lasting Windows wisdom)
2. Set DNS to 8.8.8.8 [as stated here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/716)

What could be actually happening?

Comment: Show the host ip configuration or there's few chances we may help, see [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/cannot-connect-to-chocolatey-org-or-any-other-internet-site-from-within-containe) for exemple