# Run docker inside a VirtualBox of Windows Server 2016 (GUI) on Mac OS

Tags: docker, windows

I have downloaded the Windows Server 2016 iso from Microsoft for evaluation.

I then installed it via VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro running the latest Mac OS (High Sierra).

I downloaded Docker for Windows but when I try to load it, it either fails with an error saying it cannot write to database, or it fails because it says virtualization / Hyper-V has to be enabled in BIOS.

I have Hyper-V selected in the VirtualBox settings so that should work (and restarted the virtual machine).

However it still fails.

Is it possible to run Docker for Windows on a Windows Virtual Machine, all hosted on Mac OS?

Comment: According to jcolebrand question and [comment here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/cannot-connect-to-chocolatey-org-or-any-other-internet-site-from-within-containe?rq=1#comment4399_2173) yes, it is possible. Now you should be precise on what you downloaded, version/package/url or we can't help, if you installed the previous docker for windows which run a linux VM, there's good chances that fail.

Comment: @Tensibai I downloaded from the official microsoft site -
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016 and latest official docker for windows installer

Comment: May worth giving the version (of docker mainly <with `docker --version`) in the question itself by an [edit]

Answer (score 1):

According to me this is not possible as the hyper-v should be enabled on the host system. If this is enabled in a VirtualBox, but not on the host system, then this will not work according to what I have experienced.

Comment: Confirmed that it *doesn't* work without Hyper-V enabled on the VBox host... Docker (for Windows) will fail to start, and if you open Hyper-V Manger, you will see the Moby VM stuck on "starting..." and will never complete. Too bad I have multiple dev boxes (used by others) running with VMWare Player on my host, otherwise I could switch on Hyper-V to test. Can anyone confirm it *does* work when Hyper-V is enabled on the host?